# How to pass json string with multiple record (Array) as an input parameter to pl/sql stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql-package

I have been looking so many posts over the google, but unable to accomplish. I just reviewd Sohail Anwar's post and I have exactley the same requirement. It looks like you have resolved the issues. Can you please provide me a sample package & body that you created to retrieve the json data? Same r12.2.10.

Thanks in advance
Arshad

tried so many posts over the google, but unable to accomplish.